# What does the US Govt get out of its Assured Access funding of ULA?

Tags: ula, delta-iv-heavy, atlas-v, delta-iv

ULA gets a so called subsidy (currently purported to be $800 million a year, since it is being considered to be cancelled) for Assured Access to space.

Their lack of a bid on the GPS3 launch contract has bothered congress critters, who say, if we pay for this assured access, and you do not bid, what are we getting out of the money?

Thus the question: What do we get out of the funding?

Comment: A "benefit" is a moral subjective concept which only exists for one single individual. "The government" is not a subjective individual and thus no government can ever have any benefit. So what individual do you replace your abstraction "government" with here? I'm sure there are individuals who have gained ALOT from this trick to fool naivists who say *"they are the government and our doings are therefore good for you, so you don't need to think about it, just assume it blindly!"*. You have to analyze a government as a gang of greedy individuals in order to understand why gov's do what they do.

Comment: @LocalFluff Do not disagree, was trying to be more polite about and support the fiction that govt does things of benefit.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ff_5jF_3QU&t=4029s And it's \$1 Billion ;)

Comment: I imagine the subsidy also gives the government easier access to ULA's progress, developments, patents, etc.

Comment: @LocalFluff: your definition of benefit is incorrect. A benefit can be to a group as well as an individual. No definition of 'benefit' I've found excludes governments.

Comment: @Hobbes Benefit is a subjective valuation and a single human being is the only phenomenon which can perform such a thing. Talking about benefits for anything else is an abstract way of speech, but still that is only possible given an individual's subjective valuation that "X is beneficial for Y". Benefits is not a phenomenon which exists in the physical reality, it cannot be measured objectively.

Comment: For some reason you're splitting hairs over a common, widespread use of the word 'benefit'. When a group of people (in this case, the leadership of a government agency plus everyone they need to get approval from) agree in their subjective valuation that X will benefit the country, then X is a benefit to the country. Even something as abstract as "benefit to society" is in common use. What other term would you propose to use?

Comment: The ULA used to have the market cornered on launch vehicles until Space X and Orbital etc. came along.  They used to have a contracted fixed price for many of their launch vehicles back in the day.  When that original contract ran out, the prices magically skyrocketed (pun intended) and suddenly it became unbearably expensive just to launch a SMEX, let alone a flag ship mission (NASA missions)...  I think the only thing that is benefited are companies that make up the ULA... so perhaps local jobs?

Answer (score 5):

The [goals of Assured Access to Space are](https://www.hsdl.org/?view&did=764787) (PDF of a hearing by the House Committee on Armed Services, page 14):

> The existing policy, codified in federal law, requires that assured
>   access policy and spending, at a minimum, achieve the following two objectives:
>
> 1. the availability of at least two space launch vehicles (or families of space launch vehicles) capable of delivering into space any payload designated by the Secretary of Defense or the Director of National Intelligence as a national security payload; and,
> 2. a robust space launch infrastructure and industrial base.

In other words: if necessary, the government pays to keep the launch provider from going bankrupt. The benefit to the Government is the knowledge they'll be able to launch their satellites when they need to, rather than having to wait in line with commercial customers, or worse, not be able to launch at all because a link in the supply chain controlled by foreign governments is blocked from delivering critical components.

The program failed in one respect: it continued to rely on critical components from foreign companies (i.e. the Russian RD-180) via waivers.

Assured Access is a common construct in the defence world. Companies that are strategically important are kept afloat instead of being left to fend for themselves on the open market.